# Is there any alternate way of avoiding the Foreach loop?

Tags: c#, optimization, foreach

Please look into the below code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Employee> employeeCollection = new List<Employee>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) employeeCollection.Add(new Employee {
                EmployeeID = i, 
                EmployeeName = string.Concat("Employee", i),
                Email = string.Concat("Email", i) });


            //loop thru every record
            foreach (Employee e in employeeCollection)
            {
                SendEMail(e);
            }
        }

        private static void SendEMail(Employee employee)
        {
            // do something
        }        

    }


    class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have to do some operation on every record of the Employee. Henceforth, I am using the foreach loop. If the number of records increases, the number of  operations will equally increase. So it will be O(N). 
Is there any better approach for this?

N.B.~ I am not looking for *.foreach()*

Comment: can you email be sent as one for all employees?

Comment: You want to **go through every employee** and send an email to them but the action can't be O(n)?

Comment: is it the same email to each employee?

Comment: I used Parallel.Foreach... I made a bench marking and it is fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't bother about `O(N)`. Simple algorithmic complexity is rarely a good answer regarding real-life performance. The expensive part isn't iterating over the employee list, it's sending an e-mail.

If allowed by your requirements, you could use a single e-mail with multiple recipients, for example - of course, this will only work if all the e-mails are the same. Otherwise, on some level, you just have to send *n* separate e-mails.

Of course, there's still a lot of ways to improve the perceived performance even then. You could queue all the e-mails at once, and show the user they're waiting in a queue, rather than blocking the UI. You could send each of the e-mails in parallel. You could send the e-mails to a different service (e.g. Microsoft Exchange) to handle the *actual* sending for you.

In the end, though, if you're sending 100 different e-mails, you have to send 100 e-mails. No clever algorithm will help you.

Answer (score 0):

what Luaan is saying is right.

But just to simplify your code, you can send email while adding employee in employeeCollection , you need not have to loop employeeCollection again to send email.

Something like this.

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var emp = new Employee
                {
                    EmployeeID = i,
                    EmployeeName = string.Concat("Employee", i),
                    Email = string.Concat("Email", i)
                };
            employeeCollection.Add(emp);

            SendEMail(emp);
        }
```

Comment: This isn't going to actually impact performance in any noticeable way.  The time spent actually iterating the 9 item list is all you're removing, and that's virtually nothing compared to the time that will be spent sending the emails.